# Exim logs analysis

Tags: logging, exim

Can someone help me analyze Exim log file or suggest me tool for analyzing.

```html
LINE 1
2010-12-05 17:30:15 1PPKHn-0003mA-5w <= username=example.com.br--4219--bounce@mydomain.com.br H=myserver.com.br () [174.120.195.18] P=esmtpa A=dovecot_plain:email@e-mydomain.com.br S=3851 id=4cfbe84724135_7b201579466da9b433988131@myserver.com.br.tmail

LINE 2
2010-12-05 17:30:12 H=mydomain.com.br () [111.111.111.11] Warning: Sender rate 1455.2 / 1h

LINE 3 
2010-12-05 17:30:12 1PPGo3-00010A-FL == super@domain.in R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp defer (-53): retry time not reached for any host
```

Comment: Refer to the `exim`'s specification chapter 52 that describe log format.